# What is the maximum recommended rider weight for using a dual suspension bike?

Tags: weight

I am interested in buying https://myroadeo.com/hercules-mtb-geared-bikes/27-5-29er/hannibal-27-5/ model which has dual suspension. Can a rider weighing 105 Kg, use this bicycle?

Comment: Do you really need dual suspension? Unless you're doing serious off-road riding, you almost certainly don't need it and at the price point you're looking at (15000INR is about 230USD/190EUR/160GBP), it's likely to have very low quality components and be very heavy.

Comment: Every bike should have a max recommended rider weight. 105Kg is well within common limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most department store, BSO (Bicycle Shaped Objects), and entry level bikes carry an advertised weight limit of 250lbs (113kg), which is also I imagine on the safe side, or what some would call a lawyer number. So you should be fine if you decide that is the route you want to go.

A steel framed cheap full suspension will be very heavy, and I would recommend starting with front suspension only, and an alloy model of bike if possible to save some weight – that same company offers several. Then if you ride the bike for a few years and really get into it, save up and spend a little more on a decent full suspension if you want. I ride full suspension and don't necessarily "need it" but I enjoy it more and I do a lot of trail riding with technical features. A higher end full suspension will have different levels of lock out which is a big plus when riding pavement or anything other than trails and off-road.

Comment: Thank you! I'll probably stick to front suspension. I was under the impression that riding a dual suspension gives better comfort, but as I understand now that if I go for a (low quality) rear suspension model, it may not last long.

Comment: The comfort difference will be marginal and likely negated by the suspension, as you will lose a lot of effort in the suspension bob when just pedaling along on flat surface which will result in using more energy and tiring easier.